# How to get a response from Elastic Search after indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I'm using CouchDB river plugin with Elastic Search.  In my web application, I am using CouchDB's bulk insert to insert documents into CouchDB.  This triggers the changes feed and ES reads this to index my documents.  The problem now is that my web ui isn't showing anything because ES is still indexing the documents.

I'm using PyES to "talk" to ES by the way.  Is there any function I can call to know whether Elastic Search is busy indexing?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Even if ES is indexing, ES should answer to queries.
Could you check with a

curl localhost:9200/_search?q=*

That your index has docs in it while indexing from couchDb?

[UPDATE]
You have to know that Elasticsearch is a Near Real Time search engine. So, you have to wait some seconds to be able to search for your docs.
You can retrieve your docs immediatly but you need to wait for the refresh process.

You can trigger manually the [refresh API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-refresh.html). But it could slow down dramatically your insertions.

Does it help?

Comment: The problem is that when I insert a couple (10 or so) at a go, ES needs time to index the newly added documents.  The time taken I think would be somewhere like 2-3 seconds.  When I click save, I don't have sufficient time to switch to the terminal and run that curl which would definitely give me the query results because by that time the indexing operation on the newly created documents would have been completed.

How would I speed up indexing?  Is it through adding shards or instances?